# Docker build timeout error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build my services with

```
docker-compose up --build
```

but I get this error,

```
ERROR: Service 'website' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code block for the service 'website'